# How to rename a file in request body of Postman using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, automation, postman

[image]I have put request and in the request body I have selected a file as binary. Now I want to rename the selected filename and execute the API request. How to achieve this

I have tried to get the file name from the request body:

```
var objectIdToReplace = pm.environment.get("objectId");
console.log(pm.request.body)
const body = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.file);
```

but I was getting below error:

> JSONError: Unexpected token 'o' at 1:2
> [object Object]
> ^

Comment: What does this code have to do with renaming files? It's trying to parse something as JSON when it's not actually JSON.

Comment: It's an object already, you don't need to parse it. The JSON has been parsed by the middleware.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for your reply. I got the JSON parser issue. Could you please help me, how to rename the filename in the request body

Comment: Use [`fs.rename()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrenameoldpath-newpath-callback)?